# How to dispose Wpf Child Form

Tags: c#, wpf

My application is crating a new instance of a wpf form(Child form):

```
MyWpfForm form1= new MyWpfForm ();
form1.ShowDialog();
```

There is a button on MyWpfForm for cancel and on cancel:

```
private void OnCancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

Everything is working as expected, except after closing the entire application
i can still see the `MyApplication.exe` in Window Processes.

I think MyWpfForm is not getting disposed or there may be some other reason?

Comment: It's enough to close window. Why have you decided, that the reason is "non-disposed window"?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
     MyWpfForm form1= new MyWpfForm (this);
     form1.Show();

    public MyWpfForm (ParentClass context)
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        parent = context;
        this.Owner = parent;
        parent.IsEnabled = false;

    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosing(e);
        parent.IsEnabled = true;
        parent.Focus();
    }
```